# TFS 2017 test case history

Tags: tfs

We recently upgraded from TFS 2012 to TFS 2017. In 2012 you could see the history of the test case in the Summary tab. When it was passed etc. I can't find that in 2017. Is it there?

Any guidance would be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean view the recent test results for an individual test case, then you can select the test case within a test suite and then choose to `Show/hide details pane`. Then check the `Test Result` for a specific test case.

Navigate to `Test` hub --> Select the specific `Test Plan` then `Test suite` --> Select a specific `Test Case` --> Click `Show/hide details pane` --> Select `Test results` from pane list --> view the results for a specific test case.

[image]

Besides, you can also use the REST API to get the test case and Test Run list

However, it's not so easy to get the test run history for a specific test case, unless you run only the specific test case each time. In fact, usually we will run multiple test cases in a test run.

**REST API to get the test case :**

```
GET http://SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/2017ScrumProjectFromVS/_apis/test/plans/105/suites/106/testcases/107?api-version=1.0
```

**REST API to get the test run list :**

```
GET http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/2017ScrumProjectFromVS/_apis/test/Runs/
```

> Actually the best way to retrieve test cases run status history is
>   using MTM (Microsoft Test Manager):
>
> Connect TFS server -->> Select the Team Project -->> Select  **Test**
>   tab >> Select the test plan -->> Select the specific test case -->>
>   **View Results** -->> At the end of the opened page you will see the result history (All test runs for the specific test case).

[image]

Comment: Yeah thanks. We had to install a plugin to get this called 'View Latest Test Results' , but it's exactly how you described in MTM. Cheers